can aircraft cruise speed be less than corner speed? my r-c PROPELLER plane calculations are saying cruise speed is less than corner speed.(Long read)
I have designed an aircraft and wanted to determine its performance charachteristics.
the following parameters have been utilised:
aircraft specifications:
Mtow = 1.7kg
wing_area = 0.411 m^2
Cl_max = 0.7787
Neg_Cl_max (dive against wind@-8deg) = -0.2792
Cd vs cl relationship: Cd = 0.01905227+ 0.123215108*Cl^2
max_pos_load_factor = 2.5
max_neg_load_factor = -1.25
cl vs AOA = Cl = 0.0766*AOA(deg)+0.3317

atmospheric data used:
density = 1.162 kg/m^3
using the following data i tried to draw a V-n diagram which is as follows:

for the calculations I have utilised the following formulaes:
Vstall = sqrt(2W9.81/(rhoSCl_max)) = 9.47 m/s
V_corner speed = Vstall * sqrt(load_factor_max) = 14.97m/s = approx 15m/s
dive speed or max_speed = sqrt(2* load_factor_max * W *9.81 / (rho * S *Cl_0deg)) = 22.78m/s
for the cruising speed I have used the following condition of max (Cl/Cd) for max range.
Cl_(Cl/cd_max) =sqrt(Cdo/K) = 0.3932
corresponding Cd = 2*Cdo = 0.0381
which yields a cruising speed of
V_cruise = sqrt(2w9.81/(rhoSCl_(cl/cd_max)) = 13.32m/s !! which is less than the corner speed graphically calculated.
my question is how exatly is cruising speed of an airplane calculated. I have used the max Cl/cd condition to get max range.Are my calculations wrong somewhere?
Can i use the following method to determine cruise_Speed
using the current V-n diagram i know my cruise speed must be greater than 15m/s.
I have the following formulaes for cases:

Cl/cd max which gives me
Cl = 0.3932 @ 0.08 deg(using Cl vs AOA graph),Cd = 0.0381


2)minimum power condition
cl = 0.6811 @ 4.566 deg, Cd = 0.0762

3)0 deg cruising flight
cl =0.3317,cd = 0.019
Now knowing the aero_values at respective orientation i plot graph between drag and velocity of plane with thrust vs velocity of cruising plane and seek the intersection at various throttle settings of motor as shown.


Here are my questions:
Am i wrong somewhere in my calculations? (i tried many times could use an external eye)
I know experimental data is ultimately used but why are hand calculations so off?
how is actual performance determined in industry
How does the v-n diagram of a fighter-jet/ acrobatic aircraft vary that to a commerical passenge/transport aircraft.
thank you for your valuable time.I hope you have a good day

Welcome to Aviation SE, Raptor.  Can you simplify this to only one question?  That format works best for a Q&A site like this.

out of curiosity why are pos and neg load factor bounded to so small values? (Mtow, wing area and square cube law should allow an airframe easily withstanding 10 times those loads)

hi there the entire wing and tail is held by a 3-d printed coupler that is a few layers thick.

Nobody here is going to check your homework.  Providing so much detail is not useful here.  Likewise, posting excerpts from your professor's notes (perhaps these are your versions of the notes) is questionable.
Your most likely error is one of units.
In any case, corner speed has no relation to cruise speed.  Corner speed is linked to the choice of load factor -- you could choose a very low or very high load factor.  One way or the other, it is going to change how it relates to cruise speed.  What if your maximum positive load factor was 1.1?  What if it was 100?
